# Magento 2 extend config.xml

Tags: magento-2.2.5

I am trying to disable Magento 2.2.5 core module output, such as `Magento_Backup`.

I have followed the [official documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/config/disable-module-output.html), and that works, but it requires modifying core files under the `vendor` directory.

I was hoping to extend the `config.xml` using an override.

I created `app/code/[Company]/[Module]/Magento_Backend/etc/config.xml`, with

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <advanced>
            <modules_disable_output>
                <Magento_Backup>1</Magento_Backup>
            </modules_disable_output>
        </advanced>
    </default>
</config>
```

But this does not seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in the file `app/etc/env.php`. Add the `advanced` and `modules_disable_output` sections to the config.php file (if they don’t already exist) and add the following code.

```
'system' =>
  array (
    'websites' =>
    array (
      'base' =>
      array (
        'advanced' =>
        array (
          'modules_disable_output' =>
          array (
            'Magento_Backup' => '1',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Please note it disables the module output only, not the module.

Comment: Doesn't this file get rewritten every time a module status is changed or Magento cache is flushed?

Comment: sorry, the file is app/etc/env.php

Comment: ankush, is this only disable   block output like  magento 1?

Comment: @AmitBera It's Anshu, yes it is same in Magento1, it only disables the module output and not the module. For example, the Customer module depends on the Review module, so the Review module can’t be disabled. However, if you don’t want customers to be able to provide reviews, you could turn off output from the Review module.

Comment: I tried editing the `env.php` file, it did not disable the module output like it does when editing the core file in `vendor`

Comment: @AnshuMishra, sorry bro for the typo mistake :)

Comment: @RFI What is the difference that you are seeing?

Comment: @AnshuMishra it's simply not doing anything. It does not disable the output of the module. Also, the official documentation says this change should be in the config.php. I tried both config and env and it didn't do anything for me. Only when I change the core file in vendor, does it work.

Comment: @RFI I tried same on my local and it is working for me. Please share your file path and code.